# How should I negotiate a salary with conflicting information?

Tags: negotiation

I am currently working as a temp-to-hire. The temp agency I work for has told me that the salary range I would receive at this company is 100-115 (numbers are for illustration only).

The management of the company that would hire me recently gave me a different range of 90-105 (about 15% lower than the range given by the temp agency), with an informal offer of 100 (the bottom of the range from the temp agency, near the top of the range the company provided).

Is this a negotiating tactic on the part of the new employer? Is it common to be given conflicting salary ranges when working temp-to-hire? Given that I have 2 months left before I would be officially hired, how should I approach this negotiation to maximize the salary in the new position?

Comment: Hey Daniel, I am going to give this a bit of an edit to focus the question and get you better responses. If you think I mutilated it or otherwise think it can be improved, please [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/12439/edit) it to something more to your liking.

Answer (score 3):

One may call it tactic, but, the way you have described it, it does not look far too unfair. The digits do overlap, indeed, and given a range does not necessarily imply you are granted a median (or an upper) value.

We can't tell for sure if it's tactic or not. The only thing, likewise everywhere, is a rule, *offer as few as you can and demand as much as you can*.

The other consideration I would like to draw your attention to, is **your performance**.

One of the primary goals of temp-to-hire status is *discovering how an applicant performs on their job*.

The meaning of salary range is that your final offer may vary depending on how you performed. **It's your right to fight for a better offer**, and one of the most effective ways is improving your results.

If I were you, I would come up with the following question:

> Talking to Mr. John Agent, we spoke about a different range, 100-115 units. My goal is having 110 units. Since you have a different range, **does it mean I have performed worse than you expected**? If so, I would like to improve my results so that you were glad to offer me 110.
>   I have two months before final term, it's plenty of time. Are there any ways I can improve it?
>   Can you suggest me some books to improve my knowledge?
>   During these 2 months, may I ask for tasks that require greater proficiency?

Note, you are not asking for more just because you want it. Also, you don't put your boss or an agent into an awkward situation of "conflicting information". Instead, you demonstrate your positive attitude, willingness to work and **and accomplish greater results**, ability and desire to learn, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is better to work on how to request them *your desired range* instead of thinking about whether it is a tactic or not. They offered you 100, and its your turn to counter that. For example, if you would like to receive 115, then politely request them that you need 115. Of course, while requesting this you can list all of your achievements at that company and your experience. There are several questions on this forum about "negotiating salary". Research those. For example: [Negotiation for Fulltime Conversion After Internship](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/negotiation-for-fulltime-conversion-after-internship)

Good Luck.